# Holding 2 wp_user in the same action (to update billing_email when user_email is updated)

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

iam trying to update woocommerce billing_email when user_email is updated , the problem is how to hold two objects from wp_user within the same action , in this code

```
add_action('profile_update', 'sync_woocommerce_email', 10, 2) ;

function sync_woocommerce_email( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    echo $current_user->user_email;
    echo $old_user_data->user_email."   ";

if ($current_user->user_email != $old_user_data->user_email) {
    wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'billing_email' => $current_user->user_email ) ) ;
  }
}
```

when i do this two echo i found the same email twice , but when i remove

```
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

> $old_user_data

echo the old email , which means that current_user object override the $old_user_data object , how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was frustrated by the same thing in WordPress. 
Check out my unanswered question: [Content hooks vs User hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129745/content-hooks-vs-user-hooks)

I ended up getting around it by matching the user id and updating all the user fields regardless of whether they were updated.

Until WordPress treats users' hooks the same as posts' hooks I think we're stuck with subpar processes.